# dateutil.rrule.rrule.between() gives only dates after now

Tags: python, python-dateutil, rrule

From the IPython console:

```
In [16]: b
Out[16]: datetime.datetime(2008, 3, 1, 0, 0)

In [17]: e
Out[17]: datetime.datetime(2010, 5, 2, 0, 0)

In [18]: rrule(MONTHLY).between(b, e, inc=True)
Out[18]:
[datetime.datetime(2009, 3, 6, 14, 42, 1),
 datetime.datetime(2009, 4, 6, 14, 42, 1),
 datetime.datetime(2009, 5, 6, 14, 42, 1),
 datetime.datetime(2009, 6, 6, 14, 42, 1),
 datetime.datetime(2009, 7, 6, 14, 42, 1),
 datetime.datetime(2009, 8, 6, 14, 42, 1),
 datetime.datetime(2009, 9, 6, 14, 42, 1),
 datetime.datetime(2009, 10, 6, 14, 42, 1),
 datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 6, 14, 42, 1),
 datetime.datetime(2009, 12, 6, 14, 42, 1),
 datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 6, 14, 42, 1),
 datetime.datetime(2010, 2, 6, 14, 42, 1),
 datetime.datetime(2010, 3, 6, 14, 42, 1),
 datetime.datetime(2010, 4, 6, 14, 42, 1)]
```

How do I make `between()` return dates starting from the begining (`b`) date?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to pass `b` into rrule, like this:

```
rrule(MONTHLY, dtstart = b).between(b, e, inc=True)
```

From these docs (http://labix.org/python-dateutil), it looks like calling rrule without specifying dtstart will use datetime.datetime.now() as the start point for the sequence that you're later applying `between` to.  That's why your values begin at 2009-03-06.

Comment: This also applies to https://www.npmjs.com/package/rrule